# Combine hasNextInt and value greater/less than X checks

Tags: java

Using the following method:

```
public void localsetValue(String UserInput) 
{
    System.out.println("Enter New Value:");
    while (!console.hasNextInt()){
            console.next();
            System.out.println("Must be a number.");
        }
        tempInt = console.nextInt();
        console.nextLine();



    while (tempInt <0) { 
        System.out.println("Value must be positive.");
        tempInt = console.nextInt();
    }
    SetSpecificValue(UserInput.toLowerCase(), tempInt);
}
```

The first while loop checks that the user enters a valid int; this works fine.

The second while loop checks that the user enters a positive number; this also works but at this point they can enter a letter and it'll throw out the exception.

Still new to Java, is there a way to combine these two checks?

Comment: More of a logic point of view. You would want to read the integer, check that it's positive (your code says non-negative) then go back to check the next token is an integer with nextInt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the same `while` loop and you'll be fine.

Here, we continue looping if user enters something other than an `int` OR if the entered `int` is negative.

```
int tmpInt = 0;
boolean flag = false;
while ((flag = !console.hasNextInt()) || (tmpInt = console.nextInt()) < 0){
    if (flag) {
        console.next();
        flag = false;
    }
    System.out.println("Value must be a positive integer !");
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing I still need the console.next() and console.nextLine(); parts? 

This still doesnt work quite right. If I enter a letter the error message will output. if I enter a negative value the error message will not show and the next input, valid or invalid, will always return as invalid.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop but have to combine the two abort conditions (is a number, is positive).

```
int value = -1
do {
   if(console.hasNextInt()){
      value = console.nextInt();
   } else {
      console.next();
   } 
} while(value < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public void localsetValue(String UserInput) 
{
    tempInt = -1;
    System.out.println("Enter New Value:");
    while (!console.hasNextInt() || (tempInt = console.nextInt()) <0){
            console.next();
            System.out.println("Must be a positive number.");
        }     
        console.nextLine();
    SetSpecificValue(UserInput.toLowerCase(), tempInt);
}
```